# How do you add an environment variable across pipeline.yml for BuildKite?

Tags: continuous-integration, buildkite

The BuildKite documentation suggests that you can [add environment variables that will apply to a whole pipeline.yml](https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/environment-variables#defining-your-own) file, but doesn't actually show you how to do it.

I tried something like:

```
CONCURRENCY=10

steps:

  - label: ":rocket: Let's kick this pig"
    concurrency: $CONCURRENCY

  - label: ":explosion: All out of bubble-gum"
    concurrency: $CONCURRENCY
```

But I got a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify them in an `env` block, similar to specifying the environment variables for a step.

```
env:
   CONCURRENCY: 10

steps:

  - label: ":rocket: Let's kick this pig"
    concurrency: $CONCURRENCY

  - label: ":explosion: All out of bubble-gum"
    concurrency: $CONCURRENCY
```

Which make sense, ymling all the way down.

Comment: Is it possible to sen ENV var to a result of shell script?